# SSRS Scale Out Deployment

Tags: sql-server

I have setup SSRS scaled out deployment by using two nodes cluster configured in always on availability group. Now i can access the SSRS web portal via the AG listener name via port http protocol.

Example: http://aglistenername.contoso.local/Reports/Browse

My question is, is there any way I can configure the SSRS web portal URL with https protocol?

Thank you.

Comment: It's in the Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-ssl-connections-on-a-native-mode-report-server?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Note that if you access SSRS via the AG Listener you're not really scaling out.  All the traffic will go to whichever server hosts the database.  It should be HA, though.

Comment: Since SRSS is not cluster aware, with AG it will allow to make your SSRS be highly available where it meets the requirement. What is your real thought on scaling out ssrs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a proper https certificate available and installed in both instances (i suppose you installed SSRS on both instances and i suppose also that you are using SSRS native mode).

Then open Reporting Services Configuration Manager,
click Connect at the “Reporting Services Configuration Connection” Screen;
click on Web Site URL in the left-hand pane window
In the “HTTPS Certificate” drop-down box select the certificate you installed.  You will see the Port text box pre-fill and the Report Server Web Services URL pre-fill.
Click Apply

Comment: thank you for the answer. Managed to apply the https cert from local CA to AG listener name.